# Removing Tomcat 8

Tags: linux, tomcat, centos6

I am running a Centos 6 server and I want to remove Tomcat 8, which is throwing some errors, and go to Tomcat 6, which is recommended for use with OpenEMM. I installed the package apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC3 with yum, and this is the package name shown in my folder. I am trying the following, and with the following results.

> yum remove apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC3
>   Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
>   Setting up Remove Process
>   No Match for argument: apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC3
>   Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>   * base: p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
>   * extras: p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
>   * updates: p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
>   base                          | 3.7 kB     00:00 
>   extras                        | 3.4 kB     00:00 
>   updates                       | 3.4 kB     00:00
>   No Packages marked for removal

What do I have to do to completely remove Tomcat8 with all its dependencies?

Thanks!
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that un-tarring Tomcat8 simply creates a folder and deposits the files in that folder, i.e. there is no apparent package install. A look at the installed packages using yum list supports this notion. Therefore, I simply deleted the Tomcat 8 folder and unpacked Tomcat 6, which seems to have worked just fine.